# How do I display Facebook Login status in a snackbar?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar, flutter-facebook-login

In my flutter app after logging in with Facebook SignIn, I want the user to go to the next screen if login was successful but if canceled or there is an error show a snackbar with the details. I have managed to move the user to the next screen if Login is successful but I'm having trouble displaying the snackbar.

Here's my code:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = 'login_screen';

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final FacebookAppSignIn facebookAppSignIn = FacebookAppSignIn();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenData().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           
            Container(
              height: ScreenData.screenHeight,
              // width: ScreenData.screenWidth,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: <Widget>[
                  
// Facebook login button
                      Button.signInOption(
                          onPressed: () {
                            facebookAppSignIn.fbLogin().whenComplete(() {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    
                                    return _buildFacebook(facebookAppSignIn.fbResult.status);
                                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                            
                          },
                          buttonColor: AppColors.blue,
                          iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF,
                          context: context,
                          label: 'Sign Up With Facebook',
                          labelSize: 15,
                          labelColor: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: 28),
                      
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showSnackbar() {
    _key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('Please check internet connection'),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
    ));

  }

  _buildFacebook(FacebookLoginStatus stat) {
    
    switch (stat) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
      print('_buildFacebook - user is welcome');
      return LandingScreen();
      
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
      print('_buildFacebook - cancelled  by  user');
      return LoginScreen();
      
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error: 
      return LoginScreen(); 
        break; 
        
      default: print('facebook login issue');
    }
  }
}
```

I thought about displaying the snackBar on `initState` by checking for the value of Facebook login status, but I realized that on the first screen build it would be null therefore would give errors. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can pass the `message` you want to display in a `Snackbar` to the constructor of the `LandingPage` screen. You really don't need to check for the value of the `Facebook login status`  in the next screen since your case statement already handled that.

Answer (score 0):

Use then and catchError instead of whenComplete: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Inside then, handle any expected responses, inside catchError, call the showSnackbar function inside setState.

```
setState(()=>showSnackbar());
```